# Unable to print result in a horizontal line

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Using the method of looping, write a program to print the table of 9 till N in the format as follows:
(N is input by the user)

9 18 27...

Print NULL if 0 is input

Input Description:
A positive integer is provided as an input.

Output Description:
Print the table of nine with single space between the elements till the number that is input.

Sample Input :
3
Sample Output :
9 18 27

```
N=int(input())
b=9
for i in range(1,N+1):
    if N==0:
        print("Null")
    else:
        print(i*b)
```

I tried using `"end' '"`. It didn't work.

Comment: Your code works for me. Please tell us what error or output you are getting.

Comment: `I tried using "end' '". It didn't work` Update the post to contain the code you tried.  We can't point out errors in code that you don't show us.

Comment: Just so I understand, you already tried print(i*b, end=' ') correct?

Comment: You'll need to make a string of numbers if you want to 'print in a horizontal line'.

Comment: `print` will seperate you output with a space when given values seperated with a comma like this `print(1, 2, 3)` so a good idea would be using a list comprehensive approach: `print(*[i*b for i in range(1, N+1)])` without the outter for loop.

Comment: N=int(input())
b = 9
for i in range(1,N+1):
    if N==0:
        print("Null")
    else:
        print(i*b , end=" ")

Answer (score 1):

```
N=int(input())
b = 9
if N==0:
    print("Null")
else:
    for i in range(1,N,1):
        print(i*b , end=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

you must make a list and add the items to it:

```
N = int(input())
    b = 9
    result=[]
    for i in range(1, N + 1):
        if N == 0:
            print("Null")
        else:
            result.append(i*b)
    print(result)
```

Comment: I am getting [9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72] as the output, whereas I need 9 8 27 36 as the output